# My two button microwave

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, combinatorics

Long ago, I encountered a microwave with a display in the "HH:MM:SS" format. But instead of a number pad, you entered the desired time through two buttons:

- An "up" button, which shifted the digits to the left. So "00:00:05" became "00:00:50", and "00:00:10" became "00:01:00". Note how this is not quite the same as multiplying by 10.
- A "down" button, which halved the current time, rounding down, except for "00:00:01" which stayed "00:00:01". Example: "00:01:50" became "00:00:55". The halved time is presented in the regular hours, minutes, seconds format.

A few other facts about how this worked has to be noted:

- The timer started at "00:00:01".
- The "up" button had nothing against nonsensical minutes and seconds values. "00:00:17" became "00:01:70", which made the microwave run for 130 seconds.
- If the hour value ever became larger than 23, it wrapped back to "00:00:01".
- When shifting the hours, the 10s place was just thrown away. Which means "21:20:00" became "12:00:00" and not wrapped around to "00:00:01".

(It's no longer around, so if some corner case is missing I would have to try reconstructing it from memory).

**What was the shortest time this microwave could not be set to?**
**And what was the longest time it ***could*** be set to?**

This should be possible to figure out without computers, since that's what we did, but I'm not going to stop you from having fun the way you prefer.

Test cases:

```
00:00:02 →d→ 00:00:01  Halving
00:00:03 →d→ 00:00:01  Halving with flooring
00:00:01 →d→ 00:00:01  Flooring exception, should not round down
00:00:01 →u→ 00:00:10  Shifting
00:00:10 →u→ 00:01:00  Shifting applies to digits
00:00:17 →u→ 00:01:70  Seconds and minutes allowed to be greater than 60
00:01:90 →d→ 00:01:15  Halving should format the time correctly
02:40:00 →u→ 00:00:01  Should wrap around if hours greater than 23
20:10:00 →u→ 01:00:00  Leftmost digit is lost on shifting
02:39:00 →u→ 23:90:00  Total time can be greater than 24 hours
```

Comment: Does the ending line mean [no-computers] was intentionally left out of the tags?

Comment: @bobble I'm not forbidding computers. But if that's a bad idea if I want any chance of having non-computer answers too, I can add it.

Comment: [no-computers] means you designed the puzzle to be solvable without a computer attack, and intend it to be solved that way. It's up to you whether this puzzle merits the tag.

Comment: did you really have a microwave that works like that or did you invent it just for this puzzle?

Comment: @melfnt In truth, this was a device someone specifically built at the lab (not sure if they made it before or after the problem)

Comment: Which makes it quite likely that it wasn't original even back then, and there are obviously many related puzzles where some sequence is generated through two operations. I haven't seen this floating around on the internet yet though, so here it is. I sadly have no cool brand of microwave to offer you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This puzzle is a nice variation of the [Hailstone Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture). Not quite the same, since every timer value can be increased *and* decreased. I solved it by C program, not by logic, assuming that "halve the time" does not mean "halve the number".

> The least timer value that can't be set was
>  **1384** seconds from 00:23:04
>
>  The greatest timer value that can be set is more than one day
>  **88520** seconds from 23:95:20, actually 01:00:35:20
>
>  The conditions say the clock is reset when the hour > 23
>  So it has the allowed *"nonsensical minutes and seconds values"*
>
>  That was after **7267** button presses, here are the first few in the sequence:
>  U 00:00:10
>  U 00:01:00
>  U 00:10:00
>  U 01:00:00
>  U 10:00:00
>  D 05:00:00
>  D 02:30:00
>  U 23:00:00
>  D 11:30:00
>  U 13:00:00
>  D 06:30:00
>  D 03:15:00
>  D 01:37:30
>  U 13:73:00
>  D 06:66:30
>  D 03:33:15
>  D 01:46:37
>  U 14:63:70
>  D 07:31:65
>  etc...
>
>  The button sequence was:
>  UUUUUDDUDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUUDUDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUUUUDDDUUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUUDUDUDUDDDUUUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUUDUDUDUDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUUUDDDUDDDUDDDUUUUDDDUUDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUUDUDUDDDDUDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUUUDDDDDDUDUDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUUUUDDDDUDDUDUDDDUUUUDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUUDUUDDDUDDDDUUDUDDDUDDDUUDDDDUDUDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUUDUDDDDDUDUUDDDUDDDUDDDUUDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUUDDUDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUUDUDDDDUUDUDUDDDUUDDDDUDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUUUDDDUDDDUDDDUDUUDDDUUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDDUDDUUUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUUUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUUUDDDUDDDUDUDDDUUDDDDUUUDDDDUUDDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDDUDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDUUDDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDUDUDUDDDUUDDUUDDDUUDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUUDUDDUUDDDUUDDDUDUDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUUDDDDDUDUUDDDUDUUDDDUUUDUDDDUDUDUDDDUDDDUDDDDDUDUDDDUDDDDUDDDUDUDDDDDUDUDUDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDUDUDDUDUDDDUDUDUDDDDUDDUUDDDDUDDDDDUDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDDUDUDUDDDDUDDUUDDDUDDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDUUDDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDDDUUDDDUDUDDDDUDDUDDDUDDDDDUDDUDUDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDDUDDUUDDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDDUDDUUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDUDUDUUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDDUDDUDUDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDUDDDUDUDUDUDUDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDDUDDUUDDDUDDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDDUDUDDDDUDDUUDDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDDUDDDDUDUDDUDDDDUDUDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUUDUDUDDUDDDDUDDUUUDDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDDUDUDDDDDDUUDDDDUUDUDDUDDDDUDUDDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDUDDDUDDDDUDDUUDUDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDDUDUDDDDUDDDDDDUUDDDUDDDDUDDUUDDDDDUDUDUDDUDUDDDUDDDUDDDDDUDUDDDUUDDDDDUUDDDUDUDUDDDDDUDUUDDDUDDDDDUDDDUUDUUDDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDUDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDUUDDDDUUDDDUDUDDDUDDDDUDDDUDUUDUDUDDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDUDDDDDUDDUDUDDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDDUDUDUDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDDDUDDDDUDUDDUDUDDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDUDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDDDUUDDDDUDDUDDDUDDDDDUDUDDDDUDDUUDUUDDDUDUDUDDDUDDDUUUDDDUDDDUDUDDDDDUDDDUDDUDDUDDUDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDDUDDUUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUUDUDDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDDUDUUDDDUDUDDDUUDDUDDDUDDDUUDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUUDUDDDUDDDUUDDUDDDUUDDDDUUDDDUDDDDUDDDDDUDUDDDDDDUUUDDDDDUDUDDDUUDDUDUDDDUDDDDUDDDUDDUUDDDUUDDDUUDUDUDDUDDDUDDDDUDDDUDDUUDDDDDUDUUUDDDUUDDDDUDUDUDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUUDDDUDUDUDDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDUUDDDUUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDUDDDUDDDDDUDUDDDDUDDUUDDDUDDDDUDDDDUDDUUDUDDDDUDDUDDDDUDDUUDUDDUDUDDDUUDDUDUDDUDUDDDDUDDUDDDDUDDUUDDDUDUDDDUDDDDUDDDDDUUDDDDUDUDUDDUDDDDUDUDDDDDUDUDDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDDUDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDUDDUDUUDDDUDUDUDDDUDUDDDUUDDDUDDDDUDDDDUUDDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDDUDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDUDUDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDDUDUDUDDDUDDDUDDDDUDUDDDDDUDUDDDDUUDDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDDUDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUUDDUDUDDUDUDUDDUDDDDDUDDUDDUUDDDUDDDUDDDUUDUDDDDUDUDDDDUDDDUDDDDDUDUDDDUDDDDUDDUUDDDUDUDDDUDDDUDUDDDUDUDUDDDUUDDUDDDDUDDUDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDUDDDDDUDUDDDUDDDDDUDUDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDDUDDUUDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDUDDDDUDUDDDDUDDDDDDDUDUDDUDDDUDDUDDUDDDDUDDUUDDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDUDDDDDUDDUDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDUDDDDDUDDUDUDDDDDUDUDDDUDDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDUUDDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDUDDDDUDDUUDDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDDDUDDDUUDDDUDDDDDUDDUDUDUDDDUDUDUDDDUUDDUDDUDUDDDDUDDUDDDDDDUUDDDUDDDDDUDDUDUUDDDUDDDDUDDDUDDDDDDDDDUDUDDUUDDDUDDDDUDDDDDDUUDDDUDUUDDDDDUDUDDDUDUDDDUDDDDUUUDUDDDUDUDDDUDUDUUDDDUUDDDDDDDUDDDUDDUUDDDUUDDDUDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDDDUDDUDDUDDDUDDDDUDUDUDDDDUDDUUDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDUUDDDUDUDDDDUDDDUDDDDDUUDDDDUDDDDUDUDUDDDUDUDDUDDDUDDUDDDDDDUDUDUDDDUUDUDDDUDUDDDDDUDDDUDUDDDDDDUDUDUDUDDDUDDUUDDDUDUDDDDUDDDUDDDUDUDDDDUDDUDDDDUDUUDDDDUUDDDDUDDDDDDDDDUDDUDUUDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDDDUDUUDUDDDDUDUDDDDUDDDDUDDDUDUDDDUDDDDUUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUUDDUDUDDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDDUDUDDDUDDDDUDDDDUDDDUDDUDDUDDDDDUDDUDDDDUDUUDDDUUDDUDDDUDDUDDUDDUDDDDUDUDDDDUDDDDUDDDUDDUDDDUDDDUDDUDDDUDDDDDUUDDDUUDDDUDDDDDUDUUDDDUDDDUUDDUDUDDUDDDUDDUUDDDDDDUDDUDUDDDUDDDDDDDUDDUUDDDDDDUDUDDDUDUDUDDUDUDDDDDUDUDDDUDDDUDDDDDUDDUDDUDDDDUDDUDDDDUDUUDDDUUDDDDUDUDUDDDUDDDDDUDUDDDUDDDDUUDDDDUUDDDDUDDDDUDUDDDDUDDDDUDDUUDDDDDUDDDUDDUDUDDDDUDDDDDDUDUDUDUDUDDDUDDDDUDDDDUDUUDDDUUDDDUUDDUDDDDUDUDDDDUUDDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDUUDDDUDDDUDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDUUDDDUUDDDUDUDUDDDUDDDDUDDUUDDDUDDDDUDDDDDDDDUDUDDUDDUDUDDDDDDUUDDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDDUDUDDDUDDDUDDDDDDDUDDUUDDDUDDDUDUDDDDDDUUDDDUDUDDDDUUDDDUDDDUDDDDDDDDDUDUDDUUDDDUUDDDUDDDDDUDDUDDUUDDDUDUDDDUUDDDUDDDDDDDDUDDUDDUUDDDDUUDDDUDDDDDDUDUDDDUDDDDDUUDDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDDDDDUUUDDDDDUDUDDDUDDDDDUDDUDDDDUDUDDDDUUDDDDUDDDDUDDUUDDDUDDDDDUDUDUDDDDUUDDDDDDUDUDDUDDUDDDDDUDDDUDDDDDDUUDDUDDDDDUDUDDUDDUDDDDDUDDUDUDDDDUUDDDDDUDDDDDDUUDDDUDUDDDDDDDUDDUUDDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDDUDDDDUUDDDUDDDDUUDDDUDDDDDDUDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDDUDUDDDDUUDDDDDUDUDDDUDUDDDUDDDUDUDDDDUDDDUDUDDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDDDUUDDDDDDDUDDDDDDDDUDDUDUDUDDUUDDDUDDDUDDDDDDUDUDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDDUDDDDDUDUDUDDDDDDUUDDDUDUDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDUDDDDDDUUDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDUDDDDDUDDUDUDDDDDUDUUDDDUUDDUDDDDUUDDDDDUDUDUDUDDDUDDDUDDDDDUDUUDDDUDDDDDUDUDDDDDDUDDUDDDUDUDDDUDDDDDUDUDDDUDDDDUDDDUDUUDDDUDUDUDDDDDDDDDUDDUUDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDDUDDDDDUDUDDDDDDDUDDUDUDDUDUDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDUDDDDUDDDDUUDDDUDUDDDUDDDUDDDDDDDUDDDDDDDDUDDUDDUDDUDDUDDDDUDUDDUDUDDUDDDDDDDUDDDUUDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDDUDUDDDUUDDUDDDDUUDDDDDUDDUDDDUDDDDDDDUDDDUDUDDUDUDUDDDUDUDDDDUDDDUUDDUDDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDDUDUDDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDDUDDUDDDDUDUDDDDDUDUDDDUDUDDDUDUDUDDDDUUDDDUDUDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDUDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDDUDDUUDDDUDDDDUDDDDDDDDDUDDUDDDUDDUDDDDUDDDUDDUUDDDUUDDDUDDDDDUDDDUDDUDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDDDDDDDDUDUDDDDUDUDDDDDUDDUDDUDDUDUDDDUDDDDDDUDDDDUDDDDUDDDUDDUDUDDUDDDDDUDDUUDDDDUUDDDUDDDDDDDUDUDDDDDUDDDUDUDDDDDDDUDUDDUDUDDUDDDUDDDDDDUUDDDDUDDDUDUDDDUDDDUDUDDDDDDUUDDDDUDDDDUDUDDDUUDDDUDDDDUDDDUDUDDDDUDDDUDDDDUDUDDDDDUDDDUDUDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDDUDUDDDUDUDDDUDDDDDUDDUDDDUUDDDUDDDDDUDUDDDUDUDDUDDDDUDDUUDDDUDDDUDDDDDDUUDDDDUDDUUDDDUDDDDUDDDDUDUDDDDDUDDDDUDUDDDDDDUDDUDDDDDUDUDDDUUDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDDDDUUDDDDDUDUDDDDUUDDDDDDUDDDDUDUDDDDUDDDDDUDDDUDUDUDDUDUDDDUDDDDDUDUDDDUDDDDDUDUDDDUDUDDDDDDDDUDDUDUDDUDDUDDDDDUDDUDDDUDDUDDDUDDUDDDDDUDDDUUDDDUDDDDDUDUDDDDDDDUDDUUDDDUDDDUDDDDDUDUDDDDUUDDDDDUDDUDDDUDDDDDDUDDUDUDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDDDUDUDDDDUDDUDDDDDUDDDUUDDDUDDDDUUDDDDDDUUDDDUUDDDUDDDDDUDDUDDDUDDUDDUDDDDDUDDDDUDUDUDDDDDDUUDDDDDDUDDDDDDUDDUUDUDDDDDDUDUDDDDUDDDDDDUDDDDDDDUDUDUDUDDUDDUDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDDUDDDUDUDDDDDDDUDUDDUDDDUUDDDDDDUUDDDUDDDDDUDUDDDDUUDDDUDDDUDUDDDDUDDDUDUDUDUDDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDDDUUDDDDDUDDDDUUDDDDUDDUDUDDDUDDDDUUDDDDDUDDDDDDUDDUDDUDUDDDUUDDDUUDDDDDUDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDUDDUDUDDUDDDUDDDDDDDDUDUDDDDUDDUDUDDDDUDDDUDUDDDDUDDUDDDUDDDDUDDUUDDDDUUDDUDDDDDDUUDDDDDUDDUDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDDDUDDUDDDDDUDDDDUUDDDUDDDDUUDDDDDUDDUDUDDDUDDDDDUDUDDDUDDDDUDDDDDUDDUDUDDDUDUDDDUDDDUDDDDDUDDDDUDDUDDDDDUDUDDUDUDDDDDUDDDDUUDDDUUDDDDUDDDDUDUDDDDDUDUDDDDDUDUDDDDDDDUDDDUDDUUDDDUDDDDUDDDUDDDDDDUUDDDDUDDDUDUDDDUDDDDUDDDDDDDUDDUUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDDDUUDDDUDDDDDDUDUDDDUDDDDUDDDDUDUDDDUDDDUDDUDDDDUDUDDDUDUDDDUDDDDDDUUDDDDDUDUDDDUDDDDUUDDDUDDDDDUDDUDDUDDDDDDDUDDUDUDDDUDDDUDUDDDDUDDDDUDDDUDUDDDUDDDUDUDDDUDUDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDUDDDDUDDDUDUDUDDDDUDUDDDDUDDDDDDDDDUDUDDUUDDDDUDDDDUUDDDU

I think it would be rather hard to work them out by hand.
Here is the (recursive) C code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define DIGITS      6
#define MAXSECS     10000000    // unreasonably large
#define MAXLEVEL    8000        // found earlier, empirically

char seq[MAXLEVEL];
char repeat[MAXSECS];
char found[MAXSECS];
int carryval[DIGITS] = { 0, 10, 6, 10, 6, 10 };
int maxec;

void recur(int level, int *arr)
{
    // convert to decimal value
    int decim = arr[0];
    for(int i = 1; i < DIGITS; i++)
        decim = decim * 10 + arr[i];
    if(decim >= MAXSECS)
        return;         // unlikely precaution
    if(repeat[decim])
        return;         // is cyclic
    repeat[decim] = 1;
        
    // convert to seconds
    int timer = (arr[0] * 10 + arr[1]) * 3600
              + (arr[2] * 10 + arr[3]) * 60
              +  arr[4] * 10 + arr[5];
    if(timer >= MAXSECS)
        return;         // unlikely precaution
    found[timer] = 1;

    // find max possible
    if(maxec < timer) {
        maxec = timer;
        int days = timer / 86400;
        timer %= 86400;
        int hrs = timer / 3600;
        timer %= 3600;
        int mins = timer / 60;
        int secs = timer % 60;
        
        printf("Max timer = %d seconds from %d%d:%d%d:%d%d, actually %02d:%02d:%02d:%02d, sequence length = %d\n", maxec, 
                arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4], arr[5], 
                days, hrs, mins, secs, level);
                
        for(int i = 0; i < level; i++)
            printf("%c", seq[i]);
        printf("\n\n");
    }
    
    int clk[DIGITS];
    
    // up button - shift left
    for(int i = 0; i < DIGITS - 1; i++)
        clk[i] = arr[i + 1];
    clk[DIGITS - 1] = 0;
    if(clk[0] * 10 + clk[1] < 24) {     // otherwise repeats from 1 second
        seq[level] = 'U';
        recur(level + 1, clk);
    }
    
    // down button - halve the time
    int carry = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < DIGITS; i++) {
        clk[i] = (carry * carryval[i] + arr[i]) / 2;
        carry = arr[i] & 1;
    }
    seq[level] = 'D';
    recur(level + 1, clk);
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[DIGITS] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 };
    recur(0, arr);
    
    // find smallest time not set
    for(int i = 1; i < 86400; i++) {
        if(found[i] == 0) {
            printf("Not found: %d seconds from %02d:%02d:%02d\n", i, 
                i / 3600, (i % 3600) / 60, i % 60);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, but I believe your "is cyclic" test is incorrect and is throwing off your results. (It will stop 00:00:60 if 00:01:00 has been reached, but those two behave differently for the up button)

Comment: That's a good point: back to the drawing board...

Comment: I'm actually surprised the sequences grow so long, I didn't have a constructive proof. (then again, generating *optimal* sequences is probably a whole lot harder)

Comment: I think the code can be mended by a separate "found" array, where the timestamps are treated as a six-digit decimal number, which is only used for the cyclic check.

Comment: That's what I was doing... it makes the sequence *much longer*, and with different results.

Comment: I didn't consider finding the same result in a shorter sequence. Also, I just noticed that the last example of halving has *"nonsensical minutes and seconds values"* resulting from one such being halved, but that isn't covered  by the 'down' rules.

Comment: 14:63:70 -D- 07:31:65

Comment: That's an unfortunate edge case, though that's not allowed per your "halve the time, not halve the number" interpretation, which was indeed the way I wanted it to be interpreted. "Halve the time" is presumed to put the time back into the correct format.

Comment: Curious, since your result still matches the non-constructive proof. I have some idea of why it doesn't actually matter.

Comment: If there is a good logical proof I am obviously trumped.

Comment: Too long since I've worked in c, but modifying your depth-first search, I can get 88520 seconds in 55 moves: "UDDUUUDDDDDDDUDDDUDDUDUDDDUDDUDDUDDUDDDUUDDDUDDDDUUDDDU"

Comment: I have a non-recursive version which drives the buttons from the sequence generated (a text file). The last operation from your sequence shows D 03:05:00 – U 30:50:00 which breaks 23 hours.

Comment: Optimal sequence for maximum time is 28 moves. Longest optimal sequence for any reachable time is 49 moves.

Comment: @DanielMathias can you post the 28-move sequence needed to reach 23:95:20 please?

Comment: Working on it. My code originally only kept track of the depth.

Comment: Here's the 28 move solution, I just had to change the search a little bit: https://pastebin.com/WsP6G6pv

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I can't figure out, I've been unable to detect shorter solutions, but the question does not ask for an optimum.

Comment: I was using 'n' when I needed 'list[n]' and it took a while to figure out why the sequence was 0 instead of having bits set for the "up" moves. And now I'm late with the result: UUUU.DDDU.DDDU.UDDD.UDDD.DDUU.DDDU

Comment: @DanielMathias interesting: it's a *different* (valid) 28-step sequence to the one on pastebin: `UUDD.UUDU.DDDU.UDDD.UDDD.DDUU.DDDU` differing in steps 3,4,5,6.

Comment: I changed my code to try "down" moves before "up" moves and the result: ```UDUU.DUDU.DDDU.UDDD.UDDD.DDUU.DDDU``` is yet another valid sequence.